# Filtering another model field count for each item from object_list (List View, Django)

Tags: django, listview, filtering

I am learining Django trying to create a blog. I have a ListView of Post model on Homepage. I am trying to add new context data (number of comments from separate model Comment for each item from ListView). However I wasn't able to correctly filter number of Comments for each Post by using __in (it just shows same total number of Comments on each Post item of ListView). Could you please help me with how to get a correct filter to show for each ListView Post item how many Comments does it have?

Thanks!

Post Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'запись'
        verbose_name_plural = 'записи'

    title = models.CharField('название', max_length=300, help_text='Не более 300 знаков')
    content = models.TextField('текст записи')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField('дата публикации', default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='автор')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'комментарии'

    content = models.CharField('текст комментария', max_length=500, help_text='Не более 500 знаков')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField('дата публикации', default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'автор')
    postid = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

ListView in views.py:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(postid__in = self.object_list)
        return context
```

Context data that I use in html template:

```
{% for post in posts%}
 {{ post.content }}
 {{ comments.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is to `.annotate(..)` the queryset such that each `Post` object contains an extra attribute with the number of comments:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(
        num_comments=Count('comment')
    )
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
```

In the template, you can then fetch the `.num_comment` attribute (this is only added to `Post` objects that originate from *this* `queryset`), and render it with:

```
{% for post in posts%}
   {{ post.content }}
   {{ post.num_comments }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Wasn't aware of this approach. Works really fine!